# Картинка в Collapsing Toolbar не закрывает Statusbar

Tags: java, android, collapsing-toolbar-layout

Приветствую, казалось бы все так просто, но я застрял на том, что в `Collapsingtoolbar Layout` не могу растянуть картинку так, чтобы она закрывала и `StatusBar`, мне не нужен режим `FullScreen` мне нужно чтобы когда `Collapsingtoolbar` будет раскрыт полностью, чтобы `Statusbar` становился прозрачным, перепробовал все, кроме изменения тем, в них я еще не разбираюсь. Подскажите, как быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: Уберите `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264687/toolbar-and-statusbar-overlap

Comment: @v.andrikeev Убирал, не помогает

Comment: У вас этот атрибут и в `AppBarLayout`, и в `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Вы оба убрали?
Вот вроде то, что вам нужно
https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: И со всех убирал, и с одного по отдельности, никак не уходит. Я думаю дело в темах. По сути `centerCrop` и `fitsSystemWindows` добавив в `ImageView` `StatusBar` должен был стать прозрачным, но почему-то этого не происходит.